# Week start and end dates within a month in Spark 2.4

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, dayofweek

**Requirement**: find out week start date and end date, but only within the given **month** date.

Input df:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1', '2022-07-01'), ('2', '2022-07-30'), ('3', '2022-07-31')], ["id", "date"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("date_table")

# +---+----------+
# | id|      date|
# +---+----------+
# | 1 |2022-07-01|
# | 2 |2022-07-30|
# | 3 |2022-07-31|
# +---+----------+
```

Expected output:

```
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+
| id|      date|week_start | week_end  |
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+
| 1 |2022-07-01|2022-07-01 |2022-07-02 |
| 2 |2022-07-30|2022-07-24 |2022-07-30 |
| 3 |2022-07-31|2022-07-31 |2022-07-31 |
+---+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The below query does not work, as it goes out of the boundaries of the given month (row id 1 and 3).

```py
spark.sql(""" select id,date,date_sub(date,dayofweek-1) as week_start,
                date_add(date, 7-dayofweek) as week_end FROM
                (select id,date,dayofweek(date) as dayofweek
                FROM date_table) T""")
```

Comment: This might be useful - https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/week-end-start-dayofweek-next-day/

Comment: 2022-07-01 is a Friday (at least in US), why would expect that to be the start of a week? DayOfWeek returns 1 for Sunday, 2 for Monday, etc.

Comment: @Andrew ,As per your thought what should be the start of week for "2022-07-01" ?

Comment: @punam - start of week for 2022-07-01 would be 2022-06-26. Which is what your code returns.

Comment: spark.sql(""" select date_format("2022-07-01","W") as week1,date_format("2022-06-26","W") as week2 """)
@Andrew the above dates are not falling under same week right ? then how can for start of the week  for a date 2022-07-01 can be 2022-06-26

Comment: Day of week is absolute - Sunday through Saturday.  I don't know how week of month works exactly.  But the two have nothing do do with each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the expected output, together with what you already have, you could use [`greatest`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#greatest) and [`least`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#least), providing the start and end of month respectively.

```sql
SELECT id,
       date,
       greatest(date_sub(date, dayofweek-1), trunc(date, 'MM')) as week_start,
       least(date_add(date, 7-dayofweek), last_day(date)) as week_end
FROM
    (SELECT id, date, dayofweek(date) as dayofweek
     FROM date_table) T
```

Full example:

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([('1', '2022-07-01'), ('2', '2022-07-30'), ('3', '2022-07-31')], ["id", "date"])
df.createOrReplaceTempView("date_table")

df = spark.sql(
    """
    SELECT id,
           date,
           greatest(date_sub(date, dayofweek-1), trunc(date, 'MM')) as week_start,
           least(date_add(date, 7-dayofweek), last_day(date)) as week_end
    FROM
        (SELECT id, date, dayofweek(date) as dayofweek
         FROM date_table) T
    """
)
df.show()
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# | id|      date|week_start|  week_end|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
# |  1|2022-07-01|2022-07-01|2022-07-02|
# |  2|2022-07-30|2022-07-24|2022-07-30|
# |  3|2022-07-31|2022-07-31|2022-07-31|
# +---+----------+----------+----------+
```